# Unable to change touchpad settings

Tags: touchpad, hp, 17.04, gnome-classic

Recently I have changed my desktop environment to GNOME from unity and noticed that the touchpad settings doesn't work.
how to activate reverse scrolling from terminal or any other way.

[image: output for xinput]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/838978/16-10- does this help?

Comment: It is probably the 'libinput` issue. Please add output of `xinput` TO YOUR QUESTION. PLEASE DON'T POST IT TO COMMENTS!!!!