# I cannot set the right mouse wheel scroll

Tags: mouse, hardware, scrolling, mouse-scroll, mouse-pointer

I have Ubuntu 20.10. I have problems with my mouse wheel because the scrolling has the reversed direction. There is this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604002/mouse-wheel-scrolls-in-reversed-direction), which I read. However this is not a dup because after having done all the instructions my wheel has the desired behavior but after restarting my laptop I reobtain the "wrong" scrolling. Here are all the passages:

On the terminal:

```
~$ xinput list
```

I obtain the following list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ OM                                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0504:01 04F3:312A Mouse               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0504:01 04F3:312A Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer Wireless Radio Control               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ VGA WebCam: VGA WebCam                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

after that:

```
~$ xinput list-props 11
```

I obtain:

```
Device 'OM':
    Device Enabled (179):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (181): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (316):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (317):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (318):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (319):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (320):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (321): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (322): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (323):    0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (324):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (325):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (326):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (327): 0.867647
    libinput Accel Speed Default (328): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (329):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (330):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (331):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (332): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (333): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (301): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (302):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (303):    0, 0
    Device Node (304):  "/dev/input/event10"
    Device Product ID (305):    1267, 564
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (334):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (335):   1
```

In fact the natural scrolling is enabled because `libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (316):   1`. Inserting `xinput set-prop 11 316 0` it scrolls correctly but it doesn't last long.

Any idea?

Comment: In your settings, under mouse and touchpad, do you have 'natural scrolling' enabled?

Comment: @KGIII yes in fact in the fourth line of the second block you find libinput `Natural Scrolling Enabled (316):   1`. I have underlined in the question body.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, just disable it in your settings if you don't want that behavior.

Comment: @KGIII but the terminal should represent the settings? Are setting and terminal decoupled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `xinput set-prop 11 316 0` is not enough since it gives a temporary variation.
It seems obvious but in the settings, under mouse and touchpad one should disable Natural scrolling.
This gives a permanent change.